# Returning a pointer to an object ( C++ Templates ) Error

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I've been asked to switch three classes for a university assignment over to templates to make them more generic but I'm having problems when trying to return a pointer to an object from a template function.

Compiler: GCC Version - 3.4.4 ( Cygwin )

Here is the (.h):

```
  namespace node_class
    {
    template <class Item>
    class node
    {
        public:

            // CONSTRUCTOR      
            node(const Item& initial_data = 0, node* initial_link = NULL);
            ~node(){}

            // MUTATING MEMBER FUNCTIONS
            void set_data(const Item& new_data);
            void set_link(node* new_link);

            // NON-MUTATING MEMBER FUNCTIONS
            const node* link(void) const;
            node* link(void);

            const Item& data(void) const;
            Item& data(void);

        private:

            Item data_field;
            node* next_field;
    };
    }
```

Here are the two function implementations for returning a pointer to an object:

```
 template<class Item>
    const node<Item>::node* node<Item>::link(void) const
    {
        return(next_field);
    }

    template<class Item>
    node<Item>::node* node<Item>::link(void) 
    {
        return(next_field);
    }
```

Here is the errors I keeps throwing when trying to compile:

```
$ g++ -Wall node.h

node.h:73: error: expected init-declarator before '*' token
node.h:73: error: expected ';' before '*' token
node.h:79: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
node.h:79: error: expected ';' before '*' token
```

At the moment, I have a separate (.h) and (.template) with the .template being included by a include directive in the header file; But, I'm still getting these same error messages even when the implementation of the template functions is included in the (.h) like it's supposed to be.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: There's also a solution for this problem present [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379667/returning-a-pointer-to-a-struct-defined-of-a-class-multiple-scope-operators)

Answer (score 5):

`node<Item>::node` is not a type. Make your return type `node<Item>*`.

The method declarations should be:

```
const node<Item>* link(void) const;
node<Item>* link(void);
```

The definition of these methods should be:

```
template<class Item>
const node<Item>* node<Item>::link(void) const
{
    return(next_field);
}

template<class Item>
node<Item>* node<Item>::link(void) 
{
    return(next_field);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `node<Item>::node*` should just be a `node<Item>*`:

```
template<class Item>
const node<Item>* node<Item>::link(void) const
{
    return(next_field);
}

template<class Item>
node<Item>* node<Item>::link(void) 
{
    return(next_field);
}
```

### Edit

You seem a little confused on how templates work, so I'll give an overview:

The first thing to understand is: *there is no class name node*. None at all. There is a class *template* named node. What does this mean? For each type `Item` which you apply to this template, there is a corresponding class named `node<Item>`. To repeat: if `Item` is a type, then `node<Item>` is a class, but `node` is *never* a class.

But you're probably wondering "If `node` isn't a type, why can I use it like a type?", as in

```
template<class Item>
class node
{
        node* next_field;
};
```

But here, `node` is just shorthand for `node<Item>`. Don't get confused just because it *looks* like `node` is a type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ken.

One thing which I don't understand is: node<Item>*;
When the template function is instantiated, won't it return a pointer to type node<Item>* instead of a pointer to a node*?

Comment: Perfect explanation, exactly what I was asking. Thanks again, Ken.