# Returning a pointer to a struct defined of a class, multiple scope operators

Tags: c++

My header file for a basic binary tree includes the following:

```cpp
template<typename T>
    class Btree{
        // OVERVIEW:    a binary tree with flexible structure that is not sorted

    private:

        struct node {           //a container object 
            node *left;     //left and right tree
            node *right;
            T *o;       // pointer to  object of node
        };

    public:

        node *root; //pointer to the root of the tree (NULL if empty)

        node* insert (node *parent, T *child, int child);
        //MODIFIES: this
        //EFFECTS:  creates a node that stores a pointer to the new child 
        //      and returns the pointer to the node of the new child    
        //      the integer child is either 0, for left child,
        //      or anything else for right child    

            //  void printTree (node * root);
        //EFFECTS:  takes the root of a tree and prints the tree's 
        //      coordinates  

        Btree(){};  //ctor
        Btree(){}   //dtor


    };

    #include "btree.cpp"
```

My .cpp looks like this, and note that it is included at the bottom of my header to avoid template compiler errors:

```cpp
   template <typename T>
    Btree<T> :: node * Btree<T>::insert (node *parent, T *child, int child)

    {
        node *np = new node;
        np-> o = child; 
        np->left = NULL;
        np->right  = NULL;
        if (child == 0)
            parent->left = np;
        else
            parent->right = np;
        return np;
    }
```

however, I get the following compiler error:

`btree.cpp:3: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token`

I'm compiling with g++, version 4.1.2.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is C++, right?  Could you retag with that?  You'll have to get rid of one of your tags, but your question will be seen by a more appropriate audience.

Comment: *My .cpp looks like this, and not that it is included at the bottom of my header to avoid template compiler errors* Ehm what?

Comment: Please do not add those tags again! They won't help. C++ is enough.

Comment: You have two arguments named `child` — maybe that's the source of your problem? And BTW, your destructor is missing a `~`.

Comment: The destructor is also missing a ;

Comment: @JeffPaquette you only need a `;` if it's just a prototype; he provided the definition so it's not needed.

Comment: I just realized that because my member function is templated, this is what the updated fixed code looks like  : `template Btree<T> :: node * Btree<T>::insert (node *parent, T *child, int child)`  also, the second parameter int child must take a new name

Comment: @SethCarnegie, you are correct, my mistake. If I could travel back in time I would have pointed out the superfluous ; on the ctor :D

Comment: @LeilaHejazi that's still wrong, please look at my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your destructor should have a `~` in front of it, so change

```
Btree();    //ctor
Btree(){}   //dtor
```

to

```
Btree();    //ctor
~Btree(){}   //dtor
```

Second, you need `typename` before the return type of `insert` because it is a dependent type:

```
   template <typename T>
   typename Btree<T>::node* Btree<T>::insert(node *parent, T *child, int child)
// ^^^^^^^^ <- needed
   {
    node *np = new node;
    np-> o = child; 
    np->left = NULL;
    np->right  = NULL;
    if (child == 0)
        parent->left = np;
    else
        parent->right = np;
    return np;
   }
```

Also you need to rename one of your arguments, you have two named `child`.

Comment: @LeilaHejazi so did this answer your question? Sorry, I can't tell if you mean this is correct or incorrect.

Comment: yes that answered my question.  The typename was the keyword I was looking for.  It compiles now.

Comment: @LeilaHejazi ok, if it did answer the question, please click the check mark beside this answer to accept it.

Comment: I decided to remove the template from everything and it is not working anymore.....everything is the same(with templates removed except that now my function prototype looks like this  `Btree :: node * Btree ::insert(node *parent, tile *child, int childNum)`      and I get the following error:  _prototype for ‘Btree::node* Btree::insert(Btree::node*, tile*, int)’ does not match any in class ‘Btree’_
_btree.h:31: error: candidate is: Btree::node* Btree::insert(tile*, tile*, int)_

Comment: @LeilaHejazi if you examine the error, you'll see that the prototype takes arguments of types `tile*`, `tile*`, and `int`, and you're trying to define a function that takes arguments of type `node*`, `tile*`, and `int`. You'll need to change one or the other.